# is it possible Two or more email provider for one domain?

Tags: email, dns, mail-server

I have 50 emails for one domain  but out of them only few are important so it is possible that important emails are handle by one provider and others with low cost email provider so that we can cut cost of all 50 emails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure, with forwarding to another webhost

Comment: Please can you please elaborate more in high level details

Comment: Hmm, well you could let the few important email accounts stay as they are, delete all not-important emailaccounts and make a catch-all that forwards all not-important mail to an other (cheaper) domain. But if all the not-so-important mailaccounts has to be individual accounts too, then I'm not sure how